# Magento : Get Configurable Product Price From Simple Products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, javascript, price

Is it possible to get simple product price without manually updating associated fixed price or percentage?

We have more than 3000 configurable products, so it's not possible to do it manually.

Can we do this by add/edit scripts anywhere? if yes what will be the script?

Comment: You want to get price or update price? Please add more details to your question if possible with code and example.

Answer (score 0):

I fount an extension [Configurable Products use Simple Price and Product Details (CPSP)](http://www.best4mage.com/configurable-products-use-simple-price.html)